# how to speed up following pandas dataframe iteration and loc indexing

Tags: python, pandas

The following is just a part of the whole dataset. Whole dataset is milions of rows so the computation should be super fast. In any case data looks as follows:

Link to the h5 file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16aI3plRFa3M6nSIiT1XioUIgsPYl1Wg8/view?usp=sharing

What I have done is standard loc indexing

```
filename="look at the h5 file in the link"
new_centroid_trackings = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
model_name="DLC_resnet50_4mice_new_video_no_wheelFeb17shuffle1_220000"
tracking_coords = pd.read_hdf(filename)

for frame in range(tracking_coords.shape[0]):

    centroid_mouse1_x=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail1"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail2"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail3"]["x"])/3
    centroid_mouse1_y=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail1"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail2"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse1"]["tail3"]["y"])/3

    if np.isnan(centroid_mouse1_x) or np.isnan(centroid_mouse1_y):
            centroid_mouse1_y = np.nan
            centroid_mouse1_x = np.nan

    centroid_mouse2_x=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail1"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail2"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail3"]["x"])/3
    centroid_mouse2_y=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail1"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail2"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse2"]["tail3"]["y"])/3
    
    if np.isnan(centroid_mouse2_x) or np.isnan(centroid_mouse2_y):
            centroid_mouse2_y = np.nan
            centroid_mouse2_x = np.nan

    centroid_mouse3_x=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail1"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail2"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail3"]["x"])/3
    centroid_mouse3_y=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail1"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail2"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse3"]["tail3"]["y"])/3
    
    if np.isnan(centroid_mouse3_x) or np.isnan(centroid_mouse3_y):
            centroid_mouse3_y = np.nan
            centroid_mouse3_x = np.nan

    centroid_mouse4_x=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail1"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail4"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail3"]["x"])/3
    centroid_mouse4_y=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail1"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail4"]["y"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail3"]["y"])/3
    
    if np.isnan(centroid_mouse4_x) or np.isnan(centroid_mouse4_y):
            centroid_mouse4_y = np.nan
            centroid_mouse4_x = np.nan

# now concatinate the centroids to the previous ones

    new_centroid_trackings=np.concatenate((new_centroid_trackings, np.array([[centroid_mouse1_x,centroid_mouse1_y,centroid_mouse2_x, centroid_mouse2_y, centroid_mouse3_x, centroid_mouse3_y, centroid_mouse4_x, centroid_mouse4_y]])), axis=0)
```

And for this around 90 seconds is needed for 7500 rows.

Now my idea was to maybe do this with a numpy array instead with pandas dataframe. Or are there some other faster methods that can speed up the computation?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation here?

Comment: I don't understand the logic here: it seems like this code reads from part of the dataframe, and if either value is nan, then it sets both values to nan. But then it doesn't write to the dataframe anywhere. Does the loop do something?

Comment: Identation fixed and code updated. No there is no writing to the dataframe. I just want to calculate centroid elements and if any of the x or y centroid is nan then both of them are. Later the calculate d centroids are aggregated in a numpy array.

Comment: Question about the semantics of this loop: in the line `centroid_mouse4_x=(tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail1"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail4"]["x"]+tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]["mouse4"]["tail3"]["x"])/3`, the code references tail4 in the place where most of the same calculations are referencing tail2. Is this intentional, or a copy/paste mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's start by simplifying the problem. If either x or y is NaN, then you set both to NaN. But this situation never occurs: everywhere in your dataset, if either variable is NaN, then both are NaN. So you can remove this check.

---

Next, here's how to perform this average using Pandas indexing and numpy.

```
model = "DLC_resnet50_4mice_new_video_no_wheelFeb17shuffle1_220000"
mouse = ["mouse1", "mouse2", "mouse3", "mouse4"]
bodyparts = ["tail1", "tail2", "tail3"]
coords = ["x", "y"]
array = tracking_coords.loc[:, (model, mouse, bodyparts, coords)].values
```

Pandas allows loc to index multiple columns and multiple indicies. Here I'm not filtering out any rows (`:` is a wildcard) but I am filtering out some columns. For example, this drops the likelihood column and coordinates for other body parts.

Copying entire columns like this is very fast.

Then, it's converted to a numpy array at the end with `.values`.

```
nrows = array.shape[0]
ncols = array.shape[1]
# Check that all cols are present
assert ncols == len(mouse) * len(coords) * len(bodyparts)
# Reshape
# Axes are observation, mouse, bodypart, then coordinate
array.shape = (nrows, len(mouse), len(bodyparts), len(coords))
```

Now the numpy array is reshaped. This operation is very fast, because it does not modify the data - it modifies the indices used to index into the data. It's a constant time operation.

```
# Average readings across bodyparts, which is axis 2
array = array.mean(axis=2)
```

This was the point of reshaping. Since the data we want to average lies across a single axis, it can be dealt with in one vectorized operation.

```
# Flatten inner dimensions
array = array.reshape(nrows, 8)
```

This was necessary to put the data in the same shape as your example. If you want, you can skip this line; if you do, the shape will be (?, 4, 2), with the first axis being time, the second being mouse number, and the third being the coordinate, x or y.

According to my testing, this takes 10 milliseconds to process your data. I compared it to the result produced by the implementation in the question, and it matches, with two caveats:

1. Your version start with a row of zeros, which I didn't do.
2. I fixed something in your original implementation which looked like a bug to me. (Changing tail4 to tail2.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following,

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
mouses = ['mouse1', 'mouse2', 'mouse3', 'mouse4']
for frame in range(tracking_coords.shape[0]):
    centroids = np.zeros([4, 2])
    df = tracking_coords.loc[frame, model_name]
    for (n, mouse) in enumerate(mouses):

        # for each mouse calculate the [centroid_x, centroid_y] values

        centroids[n] = [(df.loc[idx[mouse], :, idx['x']])[-4:-1].mean(), 
                        (df.loc[idx[mouse], :,idx['y']])[-4:-1].mean()]
        if np.isnan(np.prod(centroids[n]):
            centroids[n] = [np.nan, np.nan]

        # Do something here with these centroid values
```

The above code takes about 20s to iterate over 9000+ columns. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi Jason, this is helpfull. I updated the code what is done with the centroid values however we are still using the dataframe (through reading in the h5 through the pd.read_hdf) I wonder if there is a way to do this without the dataframe, meaning maybe with numpy and with that avoid the slow .loc accessing

Comment: The solution does not satisfy the requirements, but I appreciate it